# SublimeCodeIntel not showing my css styles

Tags: sublimetext2

I installed SublimeCodeIntel but when I try to use the autocomplete I don't see the class that I've got in my css file. For example.

I have a css file called style.css

```
.example{
color:black;
font-size:18px;
}
```

but in my HTML I try to do `<div class="">` When I am within the quotes I get a popup with some css data but the data is just from the page I am on. I don't see `test`

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed the trouble shooting steps on the git hub page?
https://github.com/Kronuz/SublimeCodeIntel

It mentions build.sh and "Live autocompletion can be disabled in a per-language basis, using "codeintel_live_disabled_languages". Ex. "codeintel_live_disabled_languages": ['css']"